# Add days to date in CakePHP (2.6.x)

Tags: php, date, cakephp

How can I easily add a day to a date in CakePHP (2.6.x)? If there is no helper or plugin, how can it be done by code?

I tried this but CakePHP does not know the `add`-method:

```
$date = $this->request->data['Bill']['date']->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but you can't just `add()` like that because the date in your data array is not a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) object yet, it's just a plain string. If you cast it as such first, it'll work just fine. So:

```
// Create a DateTime object from the date in the data array
$date = new DateTime($this->request->data['Bill']['date']);
```

Or if you have day/month/year dropdowns instead of a text input field:

```
$date = new DateTime(implode('-', array(
    $this->request->data['Bill']['date']['year'],
    $this->request->data['Bill']['date']['month'],
    $this->request->data['Bill']['date']['day']
)));
```

Then you have a DateTime object and you can add a day to it:

```
// Add a day to this object
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1D');
```

If you then want this new date to override the old one, you can then do something like this to save the new date:

```
$this->request->data['Bill']['date'] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Unfortunately I get this `DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` as CakePHP handles it as `array`. Any idea?

Comment: @doonot You probably have separate day/month/year dropdowns generated by the FormHelper then? Updated my answer to cover that situation as well.

Comment: @Oldskool There's also [**`Model::deconstruct()`**](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-Model.html#_deconstruct)

Comment: @ndm Interesting, wasn't aware of that method, although it seems like quite some logic to achieve the same as an implode. My gut tells me an implode probably performs faster. But that's just a feeling :)